# Android equivalent of setAudioAttributes() for MediaPlayer on API lower than 21

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm setting the `AudioAttribute` for my `MediaPlayer` like this:

```
 mMediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes((AudioAttributes) new AudioAttributesCompat.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributesCompat.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE).build().unwrap());
```

But apparently:

> Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.media.MediaPlayer#setAudioAttributes

So, how should set something like `AudioAttribute` to the `MediaPlayer` under API 21? I'm setting this attribute mainly to indicate my usage of the sound, which is Ringtone, is this property still needed under API 21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`setAudioStreamType(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setAudioStreamType(int)), with the [`AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_NOTIFICATION) type.

However, you should consider using AndroidX's [MediaPlayer2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media2/MediaPlayer2) instead of the native MediaPlayer. `setAudioAttributes()` is included, and you won't have to cast and unwrap to use it.

To implement it:

```
implementation 'androidx.media2:media2:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: Is `MediaPlayer2` like a backward compatible `MediaPlayer` or are there other differences? Either way, this sounds like what I should use, I'll give it a try asap.

Comment: From my 2-second glance at it, I think it's basically a MediaPlayerCompat sort of deal. Google seems to be making a big push to deprecate and maybe even remove a lot of framework APIs in favor of AndroidX, so they might be moving away from the Compat suffix as well.

Comment: After looking into this for a while now, I still couldn't figure out how to set `MediaPlayer2`'s data source from the `Uri` I got for the ringtone. It provides a method `setDataSource()` which accept a `DataSourceDesc2` object, but I have no clue on how to transfer my `Uri` into it, can you help me with that? This whole API is pretty weird and not well documented.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/media/DataSourceDesc.Builder#setDataSource%28android.content.Context%2C+android.net.Uri%2C+kotlin.collections.MutableMap%2C+kotlin.collections.MutableList%29 looks like what you want.

Comment: Weirdly, Android Studio can't find the `DataSourceDesc` package (only `DataSourceDesc2` present). But I did find a way to convert the Uri to `DataSourceDesc` by using `new UriDataSourceDesc2.Builder(getApplicationContext(), ringToneUri).build()`. Problem solved, thank you for your help.